# Logic Issue with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

When I run this, if there is a connection, ($TRUE) the logic should go to whether the user is logged in. It moves to the Else statement which says the computer is offline?   Can someone help me find the missiing link in the script?  I am lost on this one.  True should say online, then if user is logged in the message should be Computer in use. It is showing everyone as OFFLINE?

```
Function Get-RemoteLogonStatus{
ForEach ($line in Get-Content C:\ADComputers.csv) 
 {$Computername = $line 
 if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $ComputerName -Count 2 -Quiet){
    If((Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName 
$ComputerName).username -eq $null) 
      {
    Write-Output 'No user logged in.  RESTART COMPUTER'
    ##Shutdown /r /t 0  /M \\$ComputerName
    $ComputerName    
      } 
     
    Write-Output 'Computer in Use.'
    $ComputerName

     }
else{ 
    Write-Output 'Computer  OFFLINE.'
    $ComputerName
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does your input csv file have more than just the one field? Does it have headers? Is it actually a text file where computernames are stored each on its own line? If it has headers and `Computer` is one of them, you need to use `Import-Csv` instead of `Get-COntent` and do `$Computername = $line.Computer` to get the value of just that field.

Comment: My first guess would be that there is an issue with how you are getting the computer names from the csv file. If that file is truly a csv, then you may need additional steps to extract the computer names. For example, the values in a CSV are often wrapped in quotes, which will not be removed when using get-content. As a test, alter your script to allow you to test a manually entered computer name which you know to be online.

Comment: Thank you!  I found the problem, I had to add a TRIM() for the string coming in.  Thank you for the hint!!!!!!